# What should I do if I need special analyzer in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In my textual data, I have structures like this:

> ст. ст. 40, 131, 132, 176-178, 183, ч. 2 ст. 187, 188, 184, 189, 194 KK

Where KK is the name of a codex, ст. ст., or ст. mean article, ч. mean part.
I want Elasticsearch to find a similar string using a regular expression and execute a script to process this string so that I can get tokens like these

> 40 KK, 131 KK, ..... 194 KK.

How can I get it in Elasticsearch?

Comment: I don't know if I understand correctly, you have the input "ст. ст. 40, 131, 132, 176-178, 183, ч. 2 ст. 187, 188, 184, 189, 194 KK" and you want to have an analyzer create the tokens like this:
40 KK, 131 KK, 132 KK, 176-178 KK, 183 KK, 187 KK, 188 KK, 184 KK, 189 KK, 194 KK ?

Comment: @rabbitbr yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is possible to improve this script I wrote. You would have to invoke it at indexing time to get the formatted data.

```
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline": {
    "processors": [
      {
        "script": {
          "description": "Sample handle text",
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": """
            String[] envSplit = ctx['env'].splitOnToken(',');
            ArrayList tags = new ArrayList();
            for(int i = 0; i< envSplit.length; i++) {
              String value = envSplit[i];
              if(!value.contains('KK')) {
               tags.add(value.replace('ч. 2', '')
                .replace('ст. ', '') 
                + ' KK');
              } else {
                tags.add(envSplit[i]);
              }
            }
            ctx['tags'] = tags;
          """
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "env": "ст. ст. 40, 131, 132, 176-178, 183, ч. 2 ст. 187, 188, 184, 189, 194 KK"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful. Do you know, could I use python for scripts
?